# explanation of completing the squares

Tags: factoring

Is it possible for someone explain to me the process of completing the squares? I've been having confusions about it.

please explain using this problem:
1) $144x^4-121x^2y^2+16y^4$

thank you!

Comment: Heads up- this user just joined today and it looks like they want us to provide answers to their homework assignment. (check the OP profile).

Comment: i'm actually reviewing for my math exam tomorrow and just searched up factoring exercises. sorry for coming across as just asking for answers for my homework. needed all the help i could get.

Comment: OK - good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you might do is try expanding $(12x^2 - 4y^2)^2$. When you do you get $144 x^4 - 96 x^2 y^2 + 16 y^4$. Darn it anyway!

The process of completing the square is usually all about deriving the quadratic formula, but it can be directly used to solve 'quadratic type stuff'. So if you can't simply plug into the quadratic formula, port the proof of the quadratic formula to the problem $144x^4-121x^2y^2+16y^4$ posed here. However, there are two techniques for completing the square - see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square#A_variation_on_the_technique).

Clarification: The quadratic formula tells us how to factor a quadratic equation in $x$ into two linear factors. The OP's question is (after some thought) about factoring a $4^{th}$ 'quadratic-like' degree equation in $x$ and $y$ into two  $2^{nd}$ 'quadratic-like' degree equations in those variables. In some cases you might be able to factor further, for example, $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x+y)^2$.

It won't always be so pretty of a picture, but Robert Z directly demonstrates 'how to go at it' by completing the square.

Comment: got that! thank you! lifesaver

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that 
$$X^2+Y^2=X^2+Y^2-2XY+2XY=(X-Y)^2+2XY$$
(by subtracting $2XY$ we "[complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)" $X^2+Y^2$ to the square $(X-Y)^2$).

In your case let $X=12x^2$ and $Y=4y^2$, then
$$144x^4-121x^2y^2+16y^4=(12x^2-4y^2)^2+96x^2y^2-121x^2y^2=
(12x^2-4y^2)^2-(5xy)^2$$
Are you able to complete the factorization?

Comment: i finally get it! Thank you!